# In Ember.js updating the controller property will not update the view'

Tags: ember.js

I am using the controller property as array initially the view will render once after updating the array the view is not getting updated.

Eg:

**Handlebar:**

```
{{#each records}}
    {{name}}
{{/each}}
```

**Controller:**

```
App.recordsController = App.EventHandlerController.extend({
records: null,
actions:{
//stmt1 
var array = ["test", "test2"];
this.set('records', array);
//stmt2
array.push("data");
this.set('records', array);
}

});
```

The view is not getting updated after statement 2 What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is failing because it is not valid JavaScript.  The object passed to `extend` is a JavaScript object, which consists of keys and values.  After `records: null,`, you have code that looks like it belongs in some function.  You should have seen an error in your console describing this.